# How to add multi-valued property to jcr node through python code using cURL?

Tags: python, curl, aem, jcr

[How to add multivalue property to jcr node through java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121830/how-to-add-multivalue-property-to-jcr-node-through-java-code) says a string array could be created to pass to `node.setProperty()` in Java.

However, in Python, when I create a list and try to pass it with the curl command, I get an error saying Python cannot concatenate string and list.

```
list = ["one","two"]
subprocess.Popen(['curl','-u','admin:admin','-d',"jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured",'-d',"sling:resourceType=xxxx",'-d',"accordionType=Please Select",'-d',"accordions="+list,""+path])
```

Please help.

Comment: try wrapping list with str()

Comment: Creates a single-valued property with `["one","two"]` as value

Comment: In case you need to set the type to multi with the no or single value, you could also add another key/value pair to give a type hint for the field... Something like...  accordions@TypeHint="String[]". Otherwise do as others advised and build a string

Answer (score 0):

In the list of parameters passed to `Popen()` you're trying concatenate `"accordions="`, a string, to `list`, well, a list. No wonder that Python is confused.

As far as I know, JCR Specifications do not required a REST API. You're probably referring to [Sling](https://sling.apache.org/) here, in which case you may want to add Sling in the keywords to attract experts' attention.

I'd also advice to use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) Python library instate of running external processes through `subprocess`.